# How i can use reflection with SecurityManager to make a String + object become null

Tags: java, reflection

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager(){
            @Override
            public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
            }
        });
        doSomething();
        System.out.println("if success" + System.getSecurityManager()==null);
    }
    public static void doSomething() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        //use reflection
        //Only allow answers within this method, so that the final output of 
        //the main method is true.
    }
}
```

What should I write in `doSomethis()` method?

Comment: *How i can use reflection with SecurityManager to make a String + object become null* That is **not** something you can do.

Comment: I think this task contains error, and it should be ` System.out.println("if success" + (System.getSecurityManager()==null));` and then the goal is to make it return true?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you can always add instrumentalization in runtime with reflection and add code that will nullify strings D:

Comment: @gotofinal I look forward to your answer nulling an anonymous inline string concatenation result.